# In which one of the "~/pythonX.X/site-packages/" should I put my self-written package when I have anaconda and different environments?

Tags: python, module, package, anaconda

I have written a package and I want to import and use it in different scripts from different directories.
I found out that the best way is to put it in the "site-packages" directory (better than changing the PYTHONPATH and sys.path.insert and sys.path.append, due to many answers to many questions I read here).

Now since I have anaconda and different environments within anaconda, I do not know where I should put the package? for example in which of the following directories:

1. ```
   ~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/
   ```
2. ```
   ~/anaconda3/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/
   ```
3. ```
   ~/anaconda3/envs/MY_ENV/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/
   ```

What I think is that if I put it in the first one or the second one, I can import it in any script regardless which environment and if I put it in the third directory I can import it only when I am using a script when the "MY_ENV" environment is activated. Is it true?

p.s. should I install it or just cut and paste the folder in there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in your understanding. The location where you should put your package depends on your use case and requirements.

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/: This directory is typically used for packages installed using the user-specific Python installation. If you want your package to be available globally for all users and environments on your system, you can place it here. Packages in this location can be imported from any Python environment.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/: This directory is specific to the default Anaconda Python installation. If you want your package to be available globally for all Anaconda environments, you can place it here. Packages in this location can be imported from any Anaconda environment.

~/anaconda3/envs/MY_ENV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/: This directory is specific to a particular Anaconda environment named "MY_ENV." If you want your package to be available only when the "MY_ENV" environment is activated, you can place it here. Packages in this location will only be importable when that specific environment is active.

Based on your requirement, you can choose the appropriate directory to place your package. If you want the package to be accessible from any Python environment, regardless of Anaconda, you can consider using the first or second directory. However, if you specifically want the package to be available only within a certain Anaconda environment, you can use the third directory.

Remember to ensure that you have the necessary permissions to write to the chosen directory, especially if it is a system-wide location.

Comment: thanks for answer. should I install it or just cut and paste the folder in there?